# IBM DB2 SQL | Obtain Sunday and Monday Date from YEAR and WEEK NUMBER

Tags: sql, date, db2, week-number

In IBM DB2, using only SQL, I would like to obtain a Sunday Date and a Monday Date using the YEAR and WEEK NUMBER.

I am new to IBM DB2.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming **`n_year`** is the year, and **`n_week_in_year`** is the ISO week number in that year, I used the following function:

```
  (DATE(((n_week_in_year-1)* 7)+ 1) + (n_year -1) years)
```

I get the Monday date for that week.

My response is based on reading the following article:
  [CodeNaut: Calculate Date for any given week in year](http://codenaut.blogspot.com.au/2009/01/calculate-date-for-given-week-in-year.html)

Comment: Also, there are many built in date functions documented here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0211yip/0211yip3.html.  I'm about to do something similar with `DAYOFWEEK` which tells you if a date is a Sunday, Monday, etc.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post.  I tried the link and got the "The page you requested cannot be displayed" message.

Comment: That is nutty.  The URL is correct and it works from google.  I created a short url for it https://ibm.biz/BdxTaw.  Here's the google search I did: https://www.google.com/search?q=db2+date+functions

Comment: I know...  thanks so much for posting the new link...  I'll keep this link for future reference.